# Is there any way to use @ControllerAdvice on @Service

Tags: java, spring

I have a  project requirement where I won't be having any `@Controller` or `@RestController` but I need to have a global exception handler for my service layers, so I need to configure `@ControllerAdvice` on `@Service`, please let me know if there is some other way around to do the same.

Answer (score 5):

`@ControllerAdvice` is specifically relevant to Spring MVC controllers, so you can't use it on arbitrary beans. What you're probably looking for is the regular Spring AOP support using `@Aspect`.

Comment: thanks Chrylis,  I thought there might be some twisting available on ControllerAdvice, I'll try with aspect now.